# How to get folder path of AWS s3 bucket folder to invalidate in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I want to clear the cache from Cloudfront(AWS), want to access the latest file uploaded all the time I upload it to the S3.

To invalidate a directory, all of its subdirectories, and all of the files in the directory and subdirectories:

/directory-path*

How to get the S3 folder path that works with AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the S3 folder path that works with AWS CLI"? Did you try something and it gave an error (if so, please show the error), or did you simply try it and the cache was not cleared (if so, how did you determine this)?

Answer (score 0):

in s3 folder path is called as prefix, here is the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html) for understanding s3 bucket structures.

> How to get the S3 folder path that works with AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)

Use this aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name --recursive
This will list all the prefixes and object in the specified bucket name. [s3 ls command docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html)

Also, I have a suggestion, if all you want is to invalidate cloudfront cache why don't you use just use `/*`, this will invalidate all files in the distribution, will save you from searching bucket prefix, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidation-specifying-objects

Comment: I have used invalidate /*, still the CSS files are loading from the cache and it is taking around 3-4hrs to update the files in the CloudFront cache. Any solution to that?

Comment: This is weird, because CloudFront /*, invalidates all the files in the distribution, and all the files are prefetched at edgle location of vloudfront probably they are being cached at the browser level try removing cookies and cache from browser before invalidation

Comment: Clear your local browser cache after CloudFront reports the invalidations are complete, try checking with a different browser, or verify using curl.